# Spark 1.6 Too Large Frame 17882426381

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Facing too large frame issue, increased shuffle partitions (runned from 200 to 2001) and executor memory up to (50G) and executor memory overhead - 20480 still it is failing

Also used repartition,persist technical terms still it is showing same error

Data size: 300+ million

[image]

Comment: What have you done in your code? Join?

Comment: I was doing left join with 4 tables and selecting the required columns from the four tables - Lamanus